# PHP $_SERVER Variable Security Issue - Licensing System

Tags: php

I am planning to make a licensing system. This system makes a license query according to the domain in which the software is run.

However, I ran into some security problems because we got the running domain from the $_SERVER variable.

Example Run Domain: example.com

User Intervention

```php
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = "example2.com";
```

The domain operated in this way becomes manipulable.

I need your opinion on this.

Comment: If the code is running on the customer's system, there's nothing you can do about things like this. They can modify your code to skip the licensing checks. Anything that needs to be secured has to be on your server, not the customer's machine. You can send them a licensing token that they have to send back to the license server.

Comment: @Barmar I know many programmers who use it this way. They just take the domain run with the $_SERVER variable and send it to the license server. This seems like a huge weakness.

Comment: That's like logging in with a username and no password. Anyone can send any value to the license server. You need something secret that has to be sent along with the domain.

Comment: They can then change `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, but the authentication key won't match and the license server will reject it.

Comment: @Barmar So, can the getenv function be manipulated in the same way? I need your examples and opinions on this matter.

Comment: They can manipulate the environment before running your script, and `getenv()` will read that.

Comment: Just follow industry practice and use a cryptographic authentication key.